# How to setup permanent MTU size in RHEL 7 for eth0 interface?

Tags: linux, rhel7, mtu

I am using RHEL 7 and trying to setup permanent MTU size to 8500. Not able to find a way to set it up permanently. The server does not have dhcp.conf file in it.

I am using below command for temporary solution. But the MTU size gets reset after server reboot. If anyone has luck achieving a permanent solution please suggest.

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 8500 up
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add `MTU=8500` to the config file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory (as per [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_ifcg_files) on the RHEL site).

Or, I expect there's a way to do it with `nmcli` - `nmcli con show ...` will list all the options - just look through that for MTU and then use `nmcli con mod` to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The MTU can be changed on the fly for testing.

You can set the MTU with this command:
`ip link set mtu 9000 eth0`

but remember to add to ifcfg file to make permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Create /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf and add the following lines to it

```
interface "eth0" {
supersede interface-mtu 1500;
}
```

For more details please refer to https://github.com/linux-enhancement/set_mtu.